# Jmeter: How to set jmeter.services.FileServe default value?

Tags: jmeter, default, radix

While executing the test through JMeter I found in Jmeter log:

2017/12/21 02:37:06 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/u02/project/gold' 
2017/12/21 02:37:06 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/project/gold/JMX'

I am executing the test from /u02/project/gold/apache-jmeter-3.1 but do not know from where JMeter set new base value which is another directory '/home/project/gold/JMX'?  Please let me know how I can restrict jmeter to set new base value?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache JMeter version 3.3 **FileServer** class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v3_3/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.java#L69):

```
private static final String DEFAULT_BASE = System.getProperty("user.dir");// $NON-NLS-1$
```

So it should take `user.dir` (User working directory) [Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) value as a default

If you need to override this to have another value you can set it by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
user.dir=/some/custom/path
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Another option is setting the property value via -D command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Duser.dir=/some/custom/path -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)